# About the solutions of the diophantine equation $ x×(2a-x)=b$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Let us consider a real dynamical system $s′=g(s)$. In order to study the stability of the central manifold, we reformulate the problem as follows: For given **fixed positive integers** $a,b$, I am asking if this equation
$$ x(2a-x)=b$$
has positive integer solutions $1≤x<a$.

We can find the solution:

$$x=a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b}$$

however, we need $x$ to be an integer for a given $a,b$. So, my question is about ideas that permit us to conclude that a positive integer solution $x$ exists. I notice that we do not need the concepts from mapping theory and this is just an algebraic equation.

Comment: so you want $a^2-b=c^2$ implying that $b=(a-c)\cdot (a+c)$ so, for example, you need $a-b$ to be a square in $Z/aZ$

Comment: $w=x-a, \; \;$  $w^2 = a^2 - b, \; \;$ $w^2 - a^2 = b$   all possible $w$ are given by factoring $b$

Comment: @WillJagy: But $1≤x<a$.

Comment: @Phicar: Can you elaborate with your idea.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b=b_0b_1$ a factorization of $b$. If we have

$$x=b_0,\\2a-x=b_1$$ then $$2a=b_0+b_1.$$

So $a$ must be the arithmetic mean of two factors of $b$.